# How can I align text, on my title slide, from two different boxes?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, boxes

I'm trying to match a PowerPoint template, because, well, does anybody here like PowerPoint?  Swapping the images out for those that are in the public domain, it looks something like this:
[image: trying to match]

No, I did not intentionally choose the biggest eyesore I could find.  I've gotten this far with my code:

[image: so far]

using this logo

[image: fake logo]

and the image **[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PanellusStipticusAug12_2009.jpg)** for the background.  My MWE was made with this `.tex` file

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{generic}
    \title{This Is Sort Of A Descriptive Title}
    \author{Author}
    \institute[Inst.]{Institute}
    \date{Date}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

this and this simple `beamerthemegeneric.sty` file:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\useinnertheme[shadow=true]{generic}
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm] at (current page.center) {
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{wikiCommonsPic}
        };
        \node [xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm] at (0.068\paperwidth,0.044\paperheight) {
            \includegraphics[width=0.27\paperwidth]{fakeLogo}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}{}
```

My question lies in this `beamerinnerthemegeneric.sty` file though:

```
\DeclareOptionBeamer{shadow}[true]{\def\beamer@themerounded@shadow{#1}}
\ExecuteOptionsBeamer{shadow=false}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer
\setbeamercolor{title page}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=white}
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{myCustom}[1][]{
    \vfill
    \hbox{
        \vbox{
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.4\paperwidth,sep=8pt,left,#1]{title}
                \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
                \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty
                \else
                    \vskip0.25em
                    {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle}
                \fi
            \end{beamercolorbox}
        }
        \vbox{
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.4\paperwidth,sep=8pt,left,#1]{author}
                \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
            \end{beamercolorbox}
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.4\paperwidth,sep=8pt,left,#1]{institute}
                    \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
            \end{beamercolorbox}
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.4\paperwidth,sep=8pt,left,#1]{date}
                    \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
            \end{beamercolorbox}
            \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty
            \else
                \vskip0.25em
                {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic}
            \fi
        }
    }
    \vskip0pt
}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[myCustom][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
```

How can I align the top line of the title text with the top line of the author text as in the PowerPoint?  I've tried inserting glue in various places, but many of those tries wouldn't even compile, saying I had an extra `}` (which didn't make sense to me).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this variation of `beamerinnerthemegeneric.sty` (instead of your `\vbox`es I used top aligned `minipage`s):

```
\DeclareOptionBeamer{shadow}[true]{\def\beamer@themerounded@shadow{#1}}
\ExecuteOptionsBeamer{shadow=false}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer
\setbeamercolor{title page}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=white}
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{myCustom}[1][]{
    \vfill
    \hbox{
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\paperwidth}
            \vspace*{0pt}
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.4\paperwidth,sep=8pt,left,#1]{title}
                \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
                \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty
                \else
                    \vskip0.25em
                    {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle}
                \fi
            \end{beamercolorbox}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\paperwidth}
            \vspace*{0pt}
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.4\paperwidth,sep=8pt,left,#1]{author}
                \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
            \end{beamercolorbox}
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.4\paperwidth,sep=8pt,left,#1]{institute}
                    \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
            \end{beamercolorbox}
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.4\paperwidth,sep=8pt,left,#1]{date}
                    \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
            \end{beamercolorbox}
            \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty
            \else
                \vskip0.25em
                {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic}
            \fi
        \end{minipage}
    }
    \vskip0pt
}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[myCustom][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
```

[image]

Comment: i was trying to avoid minipages, only because someone said i'd have to make slides fragile or something like that.  will that be the case with your solution?

Comment: @asia1281 No; in fact, `beamer` internally uses `minipage`s to build some of its environments (`\beamerboxesrounded`, for example); there's no problem using `minipage`s.

Comment: oh excellent, i'm always partial to elements that are already used internally.